# Go App Engine Writing to Google Datastore Hangs

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I'm writing a simple App Engine program using Go. I need to write some data to Google DataStore. The program consistently hangs when I attempt to .Put the data into storage. This has bedeviled me this entire week.

At some point, I managed to write the data to DataStore, which I realized only once I discovered how to view the uploaded data within Cloud Console. I've changed the code a lot since then, and now I can no longer write any data. It hangs every time.

Logs show nothing helpful. Only a notice that the process has timed out. No logs written from the program, only from the system.

> Process terminated because the request deadline was exceeded. (Error code 123)

I've tried changing import statements, using [this link](http://cloud.google.com/go/datastore), but it failed to compile, so I went back to [this link](http://google.golang.org/appengine/datastore) which compiles without issue.

I considered the possibility that I had somehow badly misconfigured (disfigured, perhaps?) my development environment, so I went to a clean machine and carefully went through a new install. It still hangs.

My app.yaml file:

```
runtime: go
    api_version: go1

handlers:
    - url: /.*
      script: _go_app
```

An index.yaml file I added:

```
indexes:

    - kind: Bacon
        properties:
    - name: YCode
        direction: asc
    - name: URL
    - name: Owner
    - name: Location
```

Here is my code:

```
package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore"
        "google.golang.org/appengine" 
    )

     type Bacon struct {
        YCode string
        URL string
        Owner string
        Location string
    } 

    func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
        appengine.Main() 
    }

    func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
        projectID := "fake-for-discussion-thread-787987"

        client, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
            return
        } 

        kind := "Bacon"
        name := "3"
        baconKey := datastore.NameKey(kind, name, nil)

        //Make bacon
        bacon := Bacon{
            YCode: "1",
            URL: "http://www.safeway.com",
            Owner: "Bob",
            Location: "Deli",
        }

        // I've confirmed that this is where it hangs every time.  
        // It doesn't even capture my silly fatal log entry. 
        // It just times out and finally sends a 500 Server Error.
        if _, err := client.Put(ctx, baconKey, &bacon); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to save my Bacon: %v", err)
        }

        client.Close()

    }
```

Many thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Mmmm bacon... this might be because the context is used twice (ctx in NewClient and in client.Put). Try creating a long lived app engine client in main, and reusing it in the request handler. See [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/appengine_flexible/datastore/datastore.go)

Comment: Or that the datastore.NewClient should be created with a context.Background() rather than a request context. See [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/datastore/datastore_quickstart/main.go)

Comment: I'm starting to think that the differences between running locally and on App Engine are not captured well in much of the documentation available online. Case in point: many examples do use context.Background(), but when I tried it I got a rejection from App Engine because it was "Not an app engine context." Sigh. So I resorted to embedding that section of code within the indexHandler because it generated r, which I could feed to appengine.NewContext() to get a context that App Engine found tasty.

Comment: I did manage to solve this based upon digging through the code referenced here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/building-app/storing-data .  And, more specifically here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/appengine/gophers/gophers-4/main.go .  The thing that solved my Put woes was to quit trying to create a client object and just make a call to datastore.Put. BOOM!  No more hanging, and my data wrote to Google's DataStore with great speed!

Comment: So the big takeaways here: App Engine does a lot of stuff in the background, and folds in with their DataStore service quite nicely, as long as you don't try to use the same code conventions that probably work when running locally (or on a non-App Engine machine).

Comment: Of note, I was able to forget about declaring my projectID in my code, ostensibly because App Engine knows who I am and reaches out to their other services with the right identifier. Context on App Engine is best (maybe must?) be derived from r, which appears automatically within indexHandler.  I assume it can be passed around to other funcs, but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: One oddity that I'm now chasing down: every write to DataStore is producing two entities, each with a unique key, but otherwise identical. So the battle continues!  (Yes, yes, two pieces of bacon is definitely better than one, but I should probably still fix it.)

Answer (score 3):

Okay!  So this really drove me up a wall, but I managed to crack it this morning. I had so much difficulty finding online documentation that I want to make sure I put in my (now working) code so others may be spared the pain.

Notably, I've started to suspect that the Go documentation/examples can send you down the wrong path if you're deploying to App Engine.  App Engine doesn't like some of the core Go libraries, etc. That can become very confusing when deploying to App Engine.

Also note that I put a lot of my lessons-learned in the comments from my initial question. I'm making this entry so I can properly post my fixed App Engine-specific code.

```
    //Modified to work on App Engine. May not work right locally, etc.

    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore"
        "google.golang.org/appengine" 
    )

     type Bacon struct {
        YCode string
        URL string
        Owner string
        Location string
    } 

    func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
        appengine.Main() 
    }

    func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        //This gives a context that makes App Engine happy      
        ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)

        //NOT NEEDED (Apparently, App Engine knows who you are. Creepy.)    
        //projectID := "fake-for-discussion-thread-787987" 

        //NOT NEEDED (And may actually cause you great woe!)
        //client, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
        //if err != nil {
        //  log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
        //  return
        //} 

        //Turns out that these aren't needed, either. 
        //kind := "Bacon"
        //name := "3"

        //Note the changes from my original code, including the
        //change from NameKey to NewIncompleteKey and the
        //hard-coding of Bacon in the arguments. Alternatively, you might
        //use a variable, depending on your needs. I just need bacon.
        //This causes the entity you create in Google DataStore 
        //to have a "Kind" of "Bacon"
        baconKey := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "Bacon", nil)

        //Make bacon
        bacon := Bacon{
            YCode: "1",
            URL: "http://www.safeway.com",
            Owner: "Bob",
            Location: "Deli",
        }

        // Note changes here. No more client, just a call to datastore.Put.
        // Now it works!  One caveat: I'm still trying to figure out why it writes 
        // my data twice. But, hey!  At least it's writing!
        if _, err := datastore.Put(ctx, baconKey, &bacon); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to save my Bacon: %v", err)
        }

        //No client, so no need to close.
        //client.Close()

    }
```

Cheers!

Comment: Duplicate data issue seems to have been solved. Pretty straightforward: I had the write code executing every time an instance stood up, and also every time a request hit the instance: that makes two!  I moved the datastore writing logic into a conditional that only ran upon a server request, and now it's writing once. Pretty straightforward, which is refreshing.